# Event-handler is not executing calculation

Tags: reactjs, typescript, components

I am currently learning typescript/react and I am working on a small program to practice my skills.

I am currently stuck.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

interface triangleInfo {
  base: number;
  height: number;
  area: number;
  error: string;
}

export default class triangleArea extends React.Component<triangleInfo> {
  constructor(props: triangleInfo) {
    super(props);

    //initializing variables to undefined
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      base: 0,
      height: 0,
      area: undefined,
      error: ""
    };
  }

  //Handling change of input Base and HEIGHT

  handleChange = (input: "base" | "height", value) => {
    this.setState({
      [input]: value
    });
  };

  //getArea function to calculate Area
  getArea = triangleInfo => {
    triangleInfo.preventDefault();

    const { base, height } = this.props;

    if (base > 0 && height > 0) {
      this.setState({
        area: (base * height) / 2
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        base: undefined,
        height: undefined,
        area: undefined,
        error: "Please enter the values correctly."
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { base, height } = this.props;

    let resultMarkup;

    //If error is true, prints message to the user
    if (this.props.base < 0 && this.props.height < 0) {
      resultMarkup = (
        <p className="error-m">
          There is an error, please enter positive numbers!
        </p>
      );
    }
    //if erorr is false it will print the current state of the pokemon interface.
    else {
      resultMarkup = (
        //Div with all the information retrieve from the pokemon API

        <div>
          <p>The base of the triangle is: {this.props.base}</p>
          <p>The height of the triangle is: {this.props.height}</p>
          <p>The area of the triangle is: {this.props.area}</p>
        </div>
      );
    }
    return (
      //...
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.getArea}>
          <p>Calculate the base of a triangle!</p>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="base"
            placeholder="base"
            value={base}
            onChange={e => this.handleChange("base", e.target.value)}
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            id="height"
            placeholder="height"
            value={height}
            onChange={e => this.handleChange("height", e.target.value)}
          />
          <button type="submit">Get Area</button>

          {resultMarkup}
        </form>
      </div>
      //...
    );
  }
}
```

I am expecting the user to enter any value and then calculate the new area however i dont know how to do it dynamic.

Comment: Please post some code, not just the sandbox.

Comment: sorry just feel it would be better with a visual representation on how my program is working.

Comment: No worries, I've updated your question and provided you an answer below. Also see the sandbox :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your consuming your values from `props` instead of state. When the user fills out the form, you are updating the component-state which is correct in your `handleChange()` setup. However, in `getArea()` you are using your prop-values, which do not include the data the user provided.

https://codesandbox.io/s/somemath-1il3r

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

interface triangleInfo {
  base: number;
  height: number;
  area: number;
  error: string;
}

interface MyComponentState {
  base: number;
  height: number;
  area: number;
  error: string;
}

export default class triangleArea extends React.Component<
  triangleInfo,
  MyComponentState
> {
  constructor(props: triangleInfo) {
    super(props);

    //initializing variables to undefined
    this.state = {
      base: 0,
      height: 0,
      area: 0,
      error: ""
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  //Handling change of input Base and HEIGHT
  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value } as any);
  };

  //getArea function to calculate Area
  getArea = triangleInfo => {
    triangleInfo.preventDefault();

    const { base, height } = this.state;

    if (base > 0 && height > 0) {
      this.setState({
        area: (base * height) / 2,
        error: ""
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        base: 0,
        height: 0,
        area: 0,
        error: "Please enter the values correctly."
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { base, height, area, error } = this.state;

    let resultMarkup;

    //If error is true, prints message to the user
    if (this.props.base < 0 && this.props.height < 0) {
      resultMarkup = (
        <p className="error-m">
          There is an error, please enter positive numbers!
        </p>
      );
    }
    //if erorr is false it will print the current state of the pokemon interface.
    else {
      resultMarkup = (
        //Div with all the information retrieve from the pokemon API

        <div>
          <p>The base of the triangle is: {base}</p>
          <p>The height of the triangle is: {height}</p>
          <p>The area of the triangle is: {area}</p>
          <p>{error}</p>
        </div>
      );
    }
    return (
      //...
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.getArea}>
          <p>Calculate the base of a triangle!</p>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="base"
            placeholder="base"
            name="base"
            value={base}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            id="height"
            placeholder="height"
            value={height}
            name="height"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <button type="submit">Get Area</button>

          {resultMarkup}
        </form>
      </div>
      //...
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: whenever I use state on this case I get an error. the error I get is . ____ Property 'area' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}>'.ts(2339) which happens with the base and height to. This error comes from changing this.props to this.state on consuming the values.

Comment: @DanielIsaacChavez right, that happens because we never defined an interface for your component state. See my updated solution :)

Comment: thanks that helped, could you explain how adding the other interface it makes a big change.

Comment: @DanielIsaacChavez . Yeah! This is typical TypeScript pattern. If you do not define interface for your component-state, it will be left as Read-Only, so we would not be able to make any changes to your component-state via "this.setState()". You'll have to do this for pretty much all your state-ful components.

Comment: @DanielIsaacChavez if you have any other questions please let me know. Also, if you have found my solution was helpful in resolving your problem, please mark it as the answer :)